# Spring - How to properly map Controller?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, web-applications

I made Controller that suppose to handle form information and send it to database(for now it's only printing) but when I click "submit" button the URL that comes into browser is wrong, because it implies that Controller is in my jsp folder where it's obviously not. How to fix this?

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer;

import wymysl.database.Person;
import wymysl.database.PersonsRepository;


@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterController {

PersonsRepository repo;

@RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(@ModelAttribute("Person") Person person, HttpServletRequest request ) {

    System.out.println(""+person.getName());

    return "index";

}
```

This is the form header

```
<form class="form-register" method="POST" action="/register/addPerson" commandName="Person">
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: For starters, change your request mapping to /register, not just register. Why do you require HttpServletRequest? and change action to addPerson or whatever you are doing.

Comment: For getting attributes from Form. Changed a bit code now, but still not working. Take a look

Comment: No, just change the request mapping on top of register method inside the class, keep the Controller annotation as it is for the class.

Comment: I can answer your question, but I need to see your web.xml (url pattern mapped to the dispatcher) and how your controller is wired.

Comment: Have you mounted the webapp under `/`? Because otherwise your controller will be at `/APP_NAME/register/addPerson` instead. You should use the c:url tag for those cases: `<c:url value="/register/addPerson"/>`

Comment: @nfechner What do you mean by mounting the webapp? After giving to browser direct url with appname server still is unable to find controller

Comment: No, a webapp can reside at different paths in a container (e.g. Tomcat). Usually it's the name of the deployed war file, but that can be changed. Your action-property needs to reflect the location of the webapp as well as the controller. Also, you can mount Spring's DispatcherServlet at different locations too. Please post your `web.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the POST action in your form to "action=/register" (remove the .html)
This might work or add the same to request mapping

Answer (score 0):

The only mapped url here is `/register/addPerson`, change the action parameter to this.

Comment: Changed it in my code and in post but still without effect

Answer (score 0):

There are several things, that could be wrong:

1. Are you sure, your controller has been registered with Spring? (Check the log for RegisterController)
2. You should use the c:url tag: `<c:url value="/register/addPerson"/>`
3. Since you mounted the DispatcherServlet at `/` you will need to include an mvc:resources tag in order to find other resources:

```xml
<!-- Handles GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving static content in the ${webappRoot}/resources dir --> 
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```